# why string return null in firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

```
//Anom loggin
    auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

        userdataString = newUser.UserId;
        Debug.Log("userdatastring: " + userdataString);
    });

    Debug.Log("userdatastring out: " + userdataString);
}
```

when it leaves the anonymous function, the value returns to null, but inside it, if it returns the id that I need to obtain, any idea how get the string out value?

Answer (score 1):

That firebase function is an asynchronous function which means that the inner callback won't be ran until the asynchronous function is completed (in either a successful or unsuccessful state)

This means your debug log is actually being ran before the callback of the asynchronous function has been ran.

Here's a few options of what you can do:

1. Have the firebase asyncronous function call a callback function instead when it's ready.

   ```
   public void DoAnonymousSignIn(){
       auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(OnSignInDone);
   }

   private void OnSignInDone(Task<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser> task){
       if (task.IsCanceled){
           Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
           return;
       }

       if (task.IsFaulted){
           Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
           return;
       }

       Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
       Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

       userdataString = newUser.UserId;
       Debug.Log("userdatastring: " + userdataString);
   }
   ```
2. Keep it the way you have it now with the callback being handled inline rather than with a callback function and either set a variable marking it as ready or call "SignInDone" functions directly from this (such as SignInSuccess() and SignInFailed())
3. You can also setup your own callback events and subscribe to them from your other scripts too:

   ```
   using System;

   public static Action OnSignInSuccess;
   ```

   then inside your firebase asyncronous callback you can do:

   ```
       // ... within auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync() callback

       Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
       Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

       userdataString = newUser.UserId;

       if(OnSignInSuccess != null)
           OnSignInSuccess.Invoke();
   }
   ```

   Then other scripts can subscribe and unsubscribe to this callback event with:

   ```
   void OnEnable(){
       YourScript.OnSignInSuccess += SignInSuccess;
   }

   void OnDisable(){
       YourScript.OnSignInSuccess -= SignInSuccess;
   }

   private void SignInSuccess(){
       Debug.Log("userdatastring: " + YourScript.staticInstance.userDataString);
   }
   ```

Comment: 3b. You could also make a `public UnityEvent onSignInSuccess;` and configure it just like the `onClick` callbacks of the `Button` component ;)